# Join 2 json objects to 1 in Angular 4-6

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two jsons:

First (length 200):

{date_end: "2099-12-31", id: "2341"}

{date_end: "2099-12-31" id: "2342"}
...

Second (length 200):

{type: "free", discount:"none", warranty: "yes"}

{type: "free", discount:"none", warranty: "no"}

...

How to join them to:

{date_end: "2099-12-31", id: "2341", type: "free", discount:"none", warranty: "yes"}

{date_end: "2099-12-31" id: "2342", type: "free", discount:"none", warranty: "no"}

...

I tried Object.assign but nothing happend. No result :( pls, help.

Thanks for help!

Comment: that's not json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let first = [
  {
    "date_end": "2099-12-31",
    "id": "2341"
  },
  {
    "date_end": "2099-12-31",
    "id": "2342"
  }
];

let second = [
  {
    "type": "free",
    "discount": "none",
    "warranty": "yes"
  },
  {
    "type": "free",
    "discount": "none",
    "warranty": "no"
  }
];
let result = [];
first.forEach((itm, i) => {
  result.push(Object.assign({}, itm, second[i]));
});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to combine two objects into one, you have to loop through their individual properties and create a new object, here is a sample function, run the code snippet.

```js
function deepClone(obj1, obj2) {
    // function to perform copy
    // or just return the value
    let copyOrReturnValue = function (item) {
        if (typeof item === 'object')
            return deepClone(item);
        else
            return item;
    };
    
    // new object to contain 
    // cloned properties
    let cloned = {};
    
    let copy = function(obj) {
        // loop through keys/properties-names 
        // of proposed object
        for (let key in obj) {
            // ensure copy of only 
            // the object's own properties 
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                let value = obj[key];
                if (!value) {
                    // if value is falsy, copy and continue
                    cloned[key] = value;
                }
                else if (value instanceof Array) {
                    // if value is an array, copy items out of array
                    cloned[key] = value.map(copyOrReturnValue);
                }
                else if (typeof value === 'object') {
                    // if value is an object, make copy of object
                    cloned[key] = deepClone(value);
                }
                else {
                    // else just assign value
                    cloned[key] = value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // copy first and second object
    copy(obj1);
    copy(obj2);
    
    return cloned;
}

var user = { firstName: 'users first name', lastName: 'user lastName' }

var address = { city: 'some city', state: 'some state', country: 'some country', locations: ['some location', 'some other location'] }

var userAndAddress = deepClone(user, address);
console.log(userAndAddress);
```